# Отсортировать SQL запрос согласно очередности в списке

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть такой запрос в MSSQL

```
SELECT Roles.Name
From UsersRole
INNER JOIN Roles
ON UsersRole.RoleId = Roles.Id 
WHERE UserId in ('87962cca...','e29d102c...','465665bf...','2a190b23...')
```

Как отсортировать ответ согласно порядку UserId, которые в списке?

По умолчанию роли в ответе выводятся так: `guest, user, admin, user` по мере встречи в таблице UsersRole

Хотя должны `admin, user, user, guest` согласно порядку UserId в запросе.

Сортировка ORDER BY UserId не помогает, все равно что и без нее.

Comment: Соберите список в один строковый литерал и сортируйте по `CHARINDEX(userid, '123,456,789')`.

Comment: Или вместо `in` используйте join с конструкцией `join (values('87962cca...', 1), ('e29d102c...', 2), ... ) T(UserId, Num) on UsersRole.UserId=T.UserId order by T.Num` т.е. явно пронумеруйте элементы списка заранее и сортируйте по этим номерам

Comment: `case` в сортировку по роли можно небось добавить еще?

Comment: Всем спасибо. Проверю все три варианта на производительность и выберу.